# Как создать N матриц

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.5

Написать функцию для вычисления суммы элементов матрицы расположенных ниже главной диагонали. С ее помощью найти максимальное значение такой суммы (функция) в N матрицах случайных чисел

```
import random 
n = int (input ('введіть n=')) 
m = int (input ('введіть m=')) 
a = [] 
for i in range (n): 
    a.append ([]) 
    for j in range(m): 
        a[i].append (random.randint(-5,5))
```

Comment: приведите пример кода, с чем возникают проблемы

Comment: Я дальше кода двумерной матрицы написать ничего не могу

Comment: import random
n = int (input ('введіть n='))
m = int (input ('введіть m='))
a = []
for i in range (n):
 a.append ([])
 for j in range(m):
 a[i].append (random.randint(-5,5))

Comment: Нужно добавлять код в текст вопроса, а не в комментарии, где он совершенно нечитаем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
from random import randint

def gen_matrix(rows, cols, min_val=0, max_val=10):
    return [[randint(min_val, max_val) for _ in range(cols)] 
            for _ in range(rows)]

def sum_under_diag(m):
    r = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(m):
        for j, el in enumerate(row):
            if i > j:
                r += el
    return r

N = 5
ms = [gen_matrix(rows=4, cols=4, min_val=-5, max_val=5)
      for _ in range(N)]


res = sum_under_diag(max(ms, key=sum_under_diag))
```

Проверка:

```
In [283]: ms
Out[283]:
[[[5, -3, -3, -5], [2, -4, -3, 5], [5, 4, 4, 5], [1, 1, 0, -5]],
 [[-5, 4, -2, 4], [4, 2, 0, -3], [1, 5, -4, -3], [-3, 3, -1, -2]],
 [[3, -1, 5, -5], [2, 0, -3, -3], [4, -3, -1, 0], [-3, -1, -5, 4]],
 [[-3, -5, 5, -2], [4, 4, 5, 2], [-1, -1, -2, -1], [1, 1, 5, 3]],
 [[-2, 2, 0, -2], [2, 3, 5, -4], [0, 2, 0, -1], [3, -1, 3, 2]]]

In [284]: [sum_under_diag(m) for m in ms]
Out[284]: [13, 9, -6, 9, 9]

In [285]: max(ms, key=sum_under_diag)
Out[285]: [[5, -3, -3, -5], [2, -4, -3, 5], [5, 4, 4, 5], [1, 1, 0, -5]]

In [286]: sum_under_diag(max(ms, key=sum_under_diag))
Out[286]: 13
```